# RegEx for email validation where atleast 2 char required before @

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying below RegEx which need **atleast 2** characters before **@**

`^([a-zA-Z])[^.*-\s](?!.*[-_.@]{2})(?!.\.{2})[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@([\w-]+[\w]+(?:\.[a-z]{2,10}){1,2})$`

like

NOT ALLOWED : aa.@co.kk.pp

NOT ALLOWED : aa..@co.kk.pp

NOT ALLOWED : a.a@co.kk.pp

SHOULD ALLOWED: aa@co.kk.pp

SHOULD ALLOWED: aaa@co.kk.pp

SHOULD ALLOWED: aa.s@co.kk.pp. (atleast one char after **special char** and before **@**)

SHOULD ALLOWED: aa.ss@co.kk.pp

SHOULD ALLOWED: a@co.kk.pp

Before `@` only allowed special char `. _ -` which also not consecutively like (--) also not in beginning.

i tried below RegEx also but no luck

`^[a-zA-Z)]([^.*-\s])(?!.*[-_.@]{2}).(?!.\.{2})[\w.-]+@([\w-]+[\w]+(?:\.[a-z]{2,10}){1,2})$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest keeping things simple like this:

```sh
^([a-zA-Z][\w+-]+(?:\.\w+)?)@([\w-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10})+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u7FqK2/2)

By no means it is a comprehensive email validator regex but it should meet your requirements.

**Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `[a-zA-Z]`: Match a letter
  - `[\w.+-]+`: Match 1+ of word characters or `-` or `+`
  - `(?:\.\w+)?`: Match an option part after a dot
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `@`: Match a `@`
- `(`: Start capture group #2

  - `[\w-]+`: Match 1+ of word characters or `-`
  - `(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10})+`: Match a dot followed by 2 to 10 letters. Repeat this group 1+ times
- `)`: End capture group #2
- `$`: End

Comment: can help if any `special char` comes before @ then char before that should have min 2 length ..like  aa.ss@ddd.gg  ? so before `. (DOT)` or any special char comes should followed by `min 2 char`.

Comment: i mean it should not allow `a.ss@ddd.gg`

Comment: this one failing for `ss.sss@co.kk.pp` which is before `.` is fine but now its restricting after `. (DOT)` . after DOT not needed any check..before only

Comment: sorry but it failed for `ss.s@co.kk.pp`

Comment: Hi @anubhava ...thanks for helping out .. just a thing left...the one u provide in first place was all good on top of that i added some more...https://regex101.com/r/XG1nCo/1/. can help me to include same like need atleast 1 char `a@co.kk.pp`

Comment: yes just need to revert back my logic...need only one before `@` some domain are accepting that which is weird.. so what you give in first place was right. just need that again. pls help to validate https://regex101.com/r/XG1nCo/1/  in the first group `d@we.co.ss` only not validating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232031/discussion-between-anubhava-and-shiv-kumar-baghel).